# iOS SDK Objective-C Audio Route Change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to simply set my audio to the iPhone earpiece.  No success, this seems like it would work.  Using iOS 17 on an iPhone 15 Pro. It doesn't throw any errors. Any advice appreciated.

```
@implementation AudioTogglePlugin

- (void)setAudioMode:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"... audiotoggle test ...");
    
    NSError* err;
    
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                         mode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat
                      options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                   error:NULL];
    
    [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                               error:&err];
    
    [session setActive:YES error:NULL];
    
    NSLog(@"... audiotoggle error ... %@", err);
    NSLog(@"... audiotoggle route ... %@", [session currentRoute]);
}
@end
```

The audio route stays on "Speaker":

> inputs = (
> "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x283ae0d50, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Microphone; UID = Built-In
> Microphone; selectedDataSource = Front>" );  outputs = (
> "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x283ae0dd0, type = Speaker; name = Speaker; UID = Speaker; selectedDataSource = (null)>" )>